# Variable changes when attribute changes, make it stop! Using live()

Tags: jquery, html

I am repurposing a tooltip plugin to work with the live() function. My issue is that when I set the title attribute equal to '' to disable browser tooltips, it re-fires the function and doesn't allow me to replace the title attribute with my stored date because it updates all variables that reference it. I've posted my best crack at it below. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
$('#leadgen-cpm-cost-label').live('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
    $(this).data(this, 'title', this.title);
    this.t = $(this).data('title');
    alert(this.t);
    this.title = ''; 
    this.top = (e.pageY + yOffset); this.left = (e.pageX + xOffset);

    $('body').append( '<p id="vtip"><img id="vtipArrow" />' + this.t + '</p>' );

    $('p#vtip #vtipArrow').attr("src", 'common/vtip_arrow.png');
    $('p#vtip').css("top", this.top+"px").css("left", this.left+"px").fadeIn("slow");
} else {
    this.title = this.t;
    $("p#vtip").fadeOut("slow").remove();
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not storing the original title (t) in between events. I'm also not sure what you're pulling the title element from, what HTML element is this event targeting? My guess as to a more workable solution would be something like the following, but I have to admit that I am guessing based on lack of information.

```
$('#leadgen-cpm-cost-label').live('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        if ($(this).attr('active') == 'true') { return; }
        var original_title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).data('original_title', original_title);
        alert(original_title);
        $(this).attr('title', '');
        this.top = (e.pageY + yOffset); this.left = (e.pageX + xOffset);

        $('body').append( '<p id="vtip"><img id="vtipArrow" />' + original_title + '</p>' );

        $('p#vtip #vtipArrow').attr("src", 'common/vtip_arrow.png');
        $('p#vtip').css("top", this.top+"px").css("left", this.left+"px").fadeIn("slow");
        $(this).attr('active', 'true');
    } else {
        if (($this).attr('active') != 'true') { return; }
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('original_title');
        $("p#vtip").fadeOut("slow").remove();
        $(this).attr('active', 'false');
    }
});
```

*I went ahead and added a quick activity check, this may help you out, depending on how concurrent the calls are made.*

Comment: Ok, so I'm glad you were thinking the same way as me. The element should be irrelevant. This will be a tooltip so the element could be anything from a span, to a label to an img. The problem is that the live() function is being called twice. So basically I'm getting two 'mouseovers' and THEN two 'mouseouts' . The first mouseover tells me that my title is 'Dummy Content' and then immediately after it tells me it is '' even if I store the title like you showed as a variable and then in the data() function. -- I believe that the change in value for the title is what is causing it to run again.

Comment: Any chance you have a viewable example of this?

Comment: The reason I ask about the element is more to know if the "title" attribute is valid/expected or not. But as long as you're filling it, regardless of element, I guess it should be ok.

Comment: You really should cache any jQuery elements that you reuse. Put a `var that = $(this);` at the top of your function, adn then use `that.whatever()` instead of `$(this).whatever()` throughout. This way you're not running through jQuery every time you reference that element.

Comment: itchy is ABSOLUTELY right, just fyi, and a second note to follow up on this one is that .live should not be used any longer, it has been deprecated in favor of .on which is leagues better in terms of speed.